# How to move a particular column data from tableview as up and down in javafx?

Tags: mysql, javafx

I've a tableview and  i am able to move the whole row as up and down with this code, not particular column data from that row.

my Code is .

```
ReadOnlyIntegerProperty selectedIndex = otableview.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty();

        upaction.disableProperty().bind(selectedIndex.lessThanOrEqualTo(0));
        downaction.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
            int index = selectedIndex.get();
            return index < 0 || index + 1 >= otableview.getItems().size();
        }, selectedIndex, otableview.getItems()));

        upaction.setOnAction(evt -> {
            int index = otableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            // swap items
            otableview.getItems().add(index - 1, otableview.getItems().remove(index));
            // select item at new position
            otableview.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(index - 1);

            // code to insert shuffle data in table start here
            try {

                int aaa = otableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
                InputMappingFieldModel item = otableview.getItems().get(aaa);
                headerTextField.setText(item.getImmapid().toString()); 
                System.out.println("headerTextField "+headerTextField);
                int mappingid = Integer.parseInt(headerTextField.getText());
                System.out.println("mapping id is "+mappingid);
                String sql="UPDATE IO_MAPPING iomap\n" +
                            "inner join OUTPUT_MAPPING om on(om.OUTPUT_MAPPING_ID=iomap.OUTPUT_MAPPING_ID)\n" +
                            "set iomap.OUTPUT_MAPPING_ID=?, om.FIELD_NAME=?\n" +
                            "where iomap.IO_ID="+mappingid;
                PreparedStatement psmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                int omapid=item.getImmapid();
                String filedname = item.getFieldname();
                psmt.setInt(1, omapid);
                psmt.setString(2, filedname);
                psmt.executeUpdate();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

    // code to insert shuffle data in table end here

            otableview.getColumns().setAll(ocolFileSrno, ocolFieldName, col_spaceswap, ocolFileOutputMappingId,ocolIo_id);//remove actionColUpdate from parameter list  
            otableview.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
            otableview.setItems(modelViewField);
            otableview.refresh();
        });

        downaction.setOnAction(evt -> {
            int index = otableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            // swap items
            otableview.getItems().add(index + 1, otableview.getItems().remove(index));
            // select item at new position
            otableview.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(index + 1);

            otableview.refresh();
        });
```

and i want to move a particular column as up and down . ie. i've have 4 column and want to move the data of only 2 column data from tableview up and down 
and that particular updated tableview data save in to the databse at the same series after moving the cell data up and down, but now i am able to move whole row as up and down
and shuffling of the data as up and down works in GUI but it doesn't reflect in database...anyone kindly provide me simple logic for that?

Comment: What you mean up and down?Using a ScrollBar?When you scroll down or up the data from the `database` reflected back to the `TableView`?

Comment: i am able to change the position of row as up and down on click of up button and down button.. but i want also to reflect that changed row position to be updated in database. it is just switching the cell on GUI but does not reflect in database.. i am not talking about scrollbar, i just to move the position of column data on click of button.

Comment: I don't think the update syntax is valid. Also note that a SQL table is inherently unordered. If you want to define a ordering, you need to add a column you can sort the entries by...

Comment: How to move particular column data as up and down..not whole row...??

Comment: I've 3 column and I want to move data of only two column in table view..one column is string and another one integer which I want to move..kindly help me how to move two column data as up and down..